# Why won't TEXINPUTS work?! (And how do I fix it?)

Tags: texlive, kpathsea

This is frustrating me to no end.

I'm trying to use `TEXINPUTS` to look inside a parent directory (I don't know how else to).

It refuses to do so no matter what I do.

A minimal example to illustrate the problem: running

```
mkdir -p s/
echo '\documentclass{article}\usepackage{../b}\begin{document}Hello\end{document}' > s/a.tex
echo '' > b.sty
TEXINPUTS=".:..:s:" pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode s/a.tex
```

regurgitates

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./s/a.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))

! LaTeX Error: File `../b.sty' not found.
```

which **makes absolutely no sense** since I've added `.`, `..`, **and** `sub` to `TEXINPUTS`.

Why is this failing? What in the world am I supposed to write so that `\usepackage{../b}` works?

### Edit:

Now it's occurring to me this might be intended as a "security" feature, but then why is it that if I add `--shell-escape`, the TeX file—which could now do anything it wants—is *still* be unable to read this file? That doesn't seem to make any sense... does it?

Comment: `\usepackage` is for a _name_ not a _path_ ...

Comment: @JosephWright: Huh really? I'm pretty sure I've seen it work with a path before though? In fact if you try `latexmk -cd -pdf -latexoption='-interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape' s/a.tex` it should work...

Comment: `\usepackage{../b}` should work without any fiddling with texinputs (but is not a recommended way to input a sty). But you are obviously in the s folder when starting the compilation, and b.sty is in this folder too, so you should use `\usepackage{b}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: My question is why isn't it looking at `TEXINPUTS` to determine where to look? Isn't it supposed to?

Comment: The path you added to b is taken into account. Even with texinputs it will look will not throw away the `../` you added, as b is not in the parent folder but in the current folder. This about it the other way round: If you would do  `\input{subfolder/b}`, you  wouldn't expect tex to load a b.tex living in the current folder, so why it should be different for parent folder.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Haven't I added `s` as a path to `TEXINPUTS` though? That means it should be searching for `./s/../b.sty` which is `./b.sty`, right? Just like how if I had written `\input{subfolder/b}` I would expect it to search for `./s/subfolder/b`...

Comment: it is always wrong to have a path in `\usepackage` what is the overall intent of this code, why not simply `\usepackage{b}` ?

Comment: also note that relative paths are _relative to the working directory_ not relative to the file so  in this case you just need `b.sty` from the current directory and no path search or parent directory is required at all.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I'm just making a build system for a repository of various documents and I don't have the luxury of being able to change every single document. I do wish you guys would just answer the question instead of trying to avoid it though -- at this point this is frustrating enough that I want to learn how exactly TeXLive is working, regardless of any workarounds or lack thereof. And I don't get it: how can it be "always wrong" to have `\usepackage{../blah}` when as I explained above `latexmk -cd -pdf -latexoption='-interaction=nonstopmode' s/a.tex` works just fine?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Again, note that I am **not** claiming `../b` is "relative to the file". What I am saying is that I have added **`s`** to `TEXINPUTS` and hence I expect it to be searching relative to **`s`**, because I understand that is the entire *point* of `TEXINPUTS`. So why is it not doing that? is my question.

Comment: paths beginning `.` are taken as absolute paths from the current working directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

section 5.1 of the kpathsea manual documents this behaviour

> Exception to all of the above: If the filename being searched for is
>   absolute or explicitly relative, i.e., starts with ‘/’ or ‘./’ or
>   ‘../’, Kpathsea simply checks if that file exists, with a fallback to
>   a casefolding match if needed and enabled, as described above.

So `../b` is not searched along the path, but just in the parent of the working directory.

so in this case

```
\usepackage{b}
```

(which is also more correct latex syntax)  is all that is needed here.

Comment: +1 wow thanks. What in the world is kpathsea/how did you know to look at that? For the life of me I couldn't figure out where to find documentation explaining this... (how was I ideally supposed to diagnose this?)

Comment: `texdoc kpathsea`  will start up the manual. I know because I was there at the time, I've been maintaining latex for 30 years or so:-) @Mehrdad

Comment: Ohh man I see. Thanks!